# Use a variable or parameter to specify restart value for ALTER SEQUENCE

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to restart a sequence to a specified value, where this value is specified in either a variable or passed as a parameter programically from a C# program.

The following code is an example of what I hoped would work, but didn't:

```
DECLARE @current_value AS BigInt = 60000;

ALTER SEQUENCE
    usq_MySequence
RESTART WITH
    @current_value
```

Something like this does work:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE
    usq_MySequence
RESTART WITH
    60000
```

however that's hard coded, and the program I'm interacting with will only pass parameters (Using the SqlCommand in .NET)

Is there anyway to reset a sequence with a variable or parameter?

Comment: The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx) is quite clear - the syntax diagram is full of `<constant>` and nothing else for specifying the values.

Comment: Thanks; deans answer solves the problem given the restrictions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `RESTART WITH` value must be a constant. The only way to set it with a variable is to use some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @current_value AS BigInt = 60000;
DECLARE @s nvarchar(1000);

SET @s = N'
ALTER SEQUENCE
    usq_MySequence
RESTART WITH ' + CAST(@current_value AS nvarchar(10));

EXEC (@s);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select setval('seq_name', variable, true);
```

Comment: [S0010][195] Line 4: 'setval' is not a recognized built-in function name.